# Dictionary key and value flipping themselves unexpectedly

Tags: python, xml

I am running python 3.5, and I've defined a function that creates XML SubElements and adds them under another element. The attributes are in a dictionary, but for some reason the dictionary keys and values will sometimes flip when I execute the script.

Here is a snippet of kind of what I have (the code is broken into many functions so I combined it here)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

def AddSubElement(parent, tag, text='', attributes = None):
    XMLelement = ElementTree.SubElement(parent, tag)
    XMLelement.text = text
    if attributes != None:
        for key, value in attributes:
            XMLelement.set(key, value)
    print("attributes =",attributes)
    return XMLelement

descriptionTags = ([('xmlns:g' , 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0')])
XMLroot = ElementTree.Element('rss')
XMLroot.set('version', '2.0')
XMLchannel = ElementTree.SubElement(XMLroot,'channel')
AddSubElement(XMLchannel,'g:description', 'sporting goods', attributes=descriptionTags )
AddSubElement(XMLchannel,'link', 'http://'+ domain +'/')
XMLitem = AddSubElement(XMLchannel,'item')  
AddSubElement(XMLitem, 'g:brand', Product['ProductManufacturer'], attributes=bindingParam)
AddSubElement(XMLitem, 'g:description', Product['ProductDescriptionShort'], attributes=bindingParam)
AddSubElement(XMLitem, 'g:price', Product['ProductPrice'] + ' USD', attributes=bindingParam)
```

The key and value does get switched! Because I'll see this in the console sometimes:

```
attributes = [{'xmlns:g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'}]
attributes = [{'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0', 'xmlns:g'}]
attributes = [{'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0', 'xmlns:g'}]
...
```

And here is the xml string that sometimes comes out:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>example.com</title>
    <g:description xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">sporting goods</g:description>
    <link>http://www.example.com/</link>
    <item>
        <g:id http://base.google.com/ns/1.0="xmlns:g">8987983</g:id>
        <title>Some cool product</title>
        <g:brand http://base.google.com/ns/1.0="xmlns:g">Cool</g:brand>
        <g:description http://base.google.com/ns/1.0="xmlns:g">Why is this so cool?</g:description>
        <g:price http://base.google.com/ns/1.0="xmlns:g">69.00 USD</g:price>
        ...
```

What is causing this to flip?

Comment: That's not a dictionary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
attributes = [{'xmlns:g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'}]
```

This is a list containing a set, not a dictionary.  Neither sets nor dictionaries are ordered.

Comment: Thank you, I changed `descriptionTags` to `{'xmlns:g' : 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'}` and applied `items()` to the loop and now it works.